# How to model this user packing problem?

Tags: modeling, scheduling, heuristics, packing

I have a system with $N$ resources.

There are $K$ users in the system demanding these resources.

The demand of resources for a given user $k$, $d_k$ follows $d_k\in\{1,3,6\}$

The constraints for this problem are

a. The resources assigned to any user are contiguous

b. One resource can be assigned to one user only.

c. One or more users may not get any resources.

d. An user can access only a given set of contiguous resources, its candidates.

Example,

For user 1, we have $d_1=3$, this means user 1 needs three resources out of $N$ resources.
Lets say, for this user, the number of sets of accessible contiguous resources is 4, and the sets of given resources are given as $\{\{1,2,3\},\{7,8,9\},\{11, 12,13\}, \{17,18,19\}\}$. This means, if user 1 gets its demand satisfied, the assigned resources must be of one of these 4 sets/subsets/candidates.

Similarly, let the demand of user 2 be 1, $d_2=1$, i.e., needs 1 out of $N$ resources. And it has 5 candidates.

The different sets of resources that can be assigned to this user $2$ is given by
$S_2=\{\{1\},\{9\},\{17\},\{27\},\{33\}\}$. So, for user 2, we have 5 candidates/sets/subsets of contiguous resources.

I want to serve as many users as possible.

What is an efficient heuristic model for this user packing problem.

Comment: Why heuristic but not metaheuristic?

Comment: @prubin I cannot effort the complexity (due to the iterative process) of the meta-heuristics. Also, I don't prefer to use any special toolboxes

Comment: OK ... but I'm not sure a "heuristic" will be any faster/less complex than a metaheuristic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what sort of dimensions are you looking at ($N$, $K$, $\max_k d_k$ and maximum number of compatible resource sets for any user)?

Comment: @prubin thanks. $N=100$,$K=20$,$\max_kd_k=16$ and maximum number of compatible resource set for any user is around 10. I have the feeling that the solutions you proposed will be very far from the optimal.

Comment: I ran a few experiments using approximately those dimensions. Results were 14/13/11, 15/14/11 and 14/13/10, where in each case the first result is the optimal number of users served (solving a MIP model), the second is the result for the heuristic that picks the remaining resource set with fewest conflicts and assigns it to the user with fewest choices, and the third is the heuristic that picks the remaining user with fewest choices and allocates the remaining resource set with fewest conflicts.

Comment: @prubin seems that the first heuristic that you proposed performs good which I didn't expect! would you please share your implementations for all three schemes.

Comment: See the addendum to my answer, which links to a blog post that links to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest a couple of heuristics, with absolutely no guarantee that they will perform well. They share a common data structure. Start by identifying all sets of contiguous resources useful to any user. Map each user to the set of resource sets suitable for that user (noting that a given resource set might be useful for more than one user), and each resource set to the set of users that can use it. Next, map each resource set to the set of resource sets with which it conflicts (intersects). For instance, $\lbrace 1, 2\rbrace$ and $\lbrace 2, 3, 4\rbrace$ conflict because resource 2 is contained in their intersection.

You can now proceed in a number of ways. One is to prioritize the resource sets either randomly or according to how many unserved users they would serve (I would go with a smaller user set having higher priority than a larger user set) or based on the number of surviving conflicts they have (fewer means higher priority), then take the highest priority resource and assign it to one of the users it can serve (either randomly or by picking the user with the fewest remaining options). Another is to prioritize the users based on how many of their options survive, then take the user with the fewest remaining choices and assign a resource (either randomly or based on the fewest surviving conflicts). In each case, after making an assignment, delete the user from the pool of unserved users and delete the resource *and all surviving conflicted resources* from the pool of available resources.

**Addendum**: I wrote a [blog post](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2022/05/allocating-resource-sets.html) about this that includes a link to my Java code.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. The solutions looks good. Sometimes it is difficult to follow because of the many choices you provide for user priority and resource set priority. Can you provide me the code to implement this options for a small example.

Comment: Sorry, but I have not coded this.

Comment: would you please clarify 'I would go with a smaller user set having higher priority than a larger user set'.

Comment: you mean we can prioritise the resource sets in three ways, (1) randomly, (2) according to how many unserved users they would serve and (3) based on the number of surviving conflicts they have?

Comment: Yes, assuming the basic approach is to pick a resource set at each iteration and then assign it to a suitable user. That's one of two approaches I mentioned, the other being to pick a user at each iteration and assign that user one of its qualifying resource sets.

Comment: For the first approach (assign resource set to user), my intuition is to assign the resource set compatible with the fewest unserved users, because that might reduce the number of users that you have to leave unserved due to having already assigned all compatible resource sets. The more users are "interested" in the set you are assigning, the more users lose an option when you make the assignment.

Comment: and what about the intuition behind second approach (assign user to resource set)?

Comment: The logic there is to assign the user with the fewest available options and assign them the surviving option that has the fewest remaining conflicts (and will thus reduce the options for other users as little as possible).

Comment: thanks for your answer. It seems that you are assuming that the user demand can be any integer number between $1$ to $\max_k d_k=16$, which is not correct. If you see my question it is only some given number, for example $d_k\in\{1,2,4,8,16\}$ or $d_k\in\{1,3,6,12\}$

Comment: No, I did not assume that. In my Java code, I allowed $d_k$ to be any number in some range because I did not have a specific set of legal values in mind. Neither the IP model nor the heuristics are directly affected by this. Limiting the domain of $d_k$ may reduce the amount of storage and the run time (for everything), although I'm not even sure of that. What really matters is how many allowable sets each user has, not the number of allowable set sizes. As to whether it affects how well the heuristics do relative to the optimal solution, that is a matter for experimentation.

Comment: I implemented the conflict heuristic solution. Unfortunately, it is not performing any better than the solution I have. In my solution, we start with a user and iterate over all its resource sets. Thus we check the first resource set and check if the corresponding resources are available. If available (not yet assigned to other user), the resource set is assigned to the user. If not available, check the second compliant resource set and so on. Then move on with another user.

Comment: is there a way to quantify/measure the complexity of the conflict heuristic approach in terms of big-O or other number?

Comment: If you have $N_r$ resources, $N_s$ distinct resource sets and $N_u$ users, mapping resource sets to users that can take them would be $O(N_u \cdot N_s).$ I think identifying and recording conflicts would be $O(N_r \cdot N_s^2).$ Sorting the resource sets in priority order would be $O(N_s\log(N_s)).$ Making the assignments would be $O(N_s).$ So the dominant term would seem to be $O(N_r \cdot N_s^2).$

Comment: thanks a lot. It seems that the greedy heuristic (for each user, we iterate over all (if needed) its candidate resource sets to find a suitable spot in the resource grid). Can we measure its complexity? We have $N_r$ resources, user $u$ has $N_r^{(u)}$ resource sets. If two users have same resource sets, the order they iterate over the resource sets are different.

Comment: I implemented this conflict heuristic method, i.e., user first and selecting the best resource set. Unfortunately, this is performing little worse than the another solution my fellow friend has. Is there a way to improve this performance of this solution?

Comment: I answered this on my blog. (Asking one place or the other should be sufficient; no need to ask both places.)